# Use a List and Variables in different Pages in WPF with C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list like this on my home page on my WPF (C#) project like this:

```
var sintomas = new List<string>();
```

I need to add data to that list through different pages from some Radio Buttons so I can set for example in my second page:

```
if(RadioButton.isChecked)
sintomas.Add("Something");
```

What do I have to do to initialize it and then use it on each page?

Same for variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do

```
Public static List<string>() sintomas = new List<string>();
```

Then in your other class:

```
private YourClass Yourname = new YourClass();
```

Then you could acces the list like this:

```
Yourname.sintomas.add("yay");
```

### Update

On the start of your class so after:

```
public partial class AddisHome : Window
{
```

You need to create your list like this:

```
   Public List<string> sintomas = new List<string>();
```

It's public so other classes can acces it

Then on your second class:

again on the top of your other class after:

```
    public partial class Personaldata : Window
    {
```

You need to add this:

```
private AddisHome yourvar = new AddisHome();
```

then inside your function you can call:

```
yourvar.sintomas.add("yay");
```

Comment: Where do I have to declare that?
I have a AddisHome.xaml (and AddisHome.xaml.cs) where I need to declare the variables and the list and a PersonalData.xaml (and PersonalData.xaml.cs) where I need to Add values to that list.

Comment: Let my update my answer

Comment: I updated my answer hope you can get it to work now

Comment: It worked, but when I call the list in the last page, it is empty. I'm trying to set string values thought the pages like:

If(radiobutton.ischecked)
{
this.sintomas.add("something");
}

Comment: this sintomas.add is this called on your first class or on your second one? if its on your first and you want to call the list on the second classs it should work if you do yourclass.sintomas

Comment: It seems to work, but the list just got empty on my last (or second) page. It does not keep the data.

Comment: It's working now! I was missing the "static" so the list cannot change.